# How to assign existing buttons in an Nview to an Array

Tags: arrays, xcode, button

I need help to make an Array, in xcode, to collect 25 existing buttons in a Window(NView) for, for example, change background colors or titles of others buttons when one button is pressed.

Thanks.

This is the Code:

**Botones.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

extern const NSString* Nivel[];
extern const NSString* Ayuda[];
extern const NSString* Boleo[];
BOOL Estado[5][5];
int Columna;
int Fila;
//NSColor* Rojo = (NSColor *)redColor;

@interface Botones : NSObject {
    IBOutlet id Intents;
    IBOutlet id Nivel;
    IBOutlet id BoxBot;
    NSArray *Arbot;
}

- (IBAction)OrBoton:(id)sender;
```

**Botones.m**

```
#import "Botones.h"

const NSString *Nivel[] = {@"101214",@"0002040507091517192202224",@"01030506080910111314151618192123"};
BOOL Estado[5][5] = {FALSE};
int Columna = 0;
int Fila = 0;


@implementation Botones
- (void)awakeFromNib {
Arbot = [[BoxBot subviews] copy];
}

- (IBAction)OrBoton:(id)sender {
    [Intents setIntValue:[sender tag]]; 
    Columna =[sender tag] % 5;
    Fila = [sender tag] / 5;
    if (Estado[Columna][Fila] == FALSE) {
        Estado[Columna][Fila] = TRUE;
        [sender setTitle:@"OK"];
        //[sender setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
         }
    else {
        Estado[Columna][Fila] = FALSE;
        [sender setTitle:@""];
        //[sender setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];

    }
    if (Fila > 0) {   
        if (Estado[Columna][Fila - 1] == FALSE) {
            Estado[Columna][Fila - 1] = TRUE;
            NSLog(@"%@",[BoxBot subviews]);
            [[Arbot objectAtIndex:5] setTitle:@"OK"];// <-- Don't changes button's title                
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the buttons are the only subviews in the view, you can use this:

```
//view is a variable pointing to the view containing the buttons
NSArray *buttons = [[view subviews] copy];
```

If there are other views in the view, you will have to filter them out:

```
//view is a variable pointing to the view containing the buttons
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:25];
for(NSView *v in [view subviews]) {
    if([v isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]) [buttons addObject:v];
}
```

**Edit**

```
...
@interface Botones : NSObject {
    IBOutlet id Intents;
    IBOutlet id Nivel;
    IBOutlet id BoxBot;
    NSArray *ArBot;
}
...
```

Botones.m

```
...
@implementation Botones
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    ArBot = [[BoxBot subviews] copy];
    /*or
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:25];
    for(NSView *v in [BoxBot subviews]) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]) [array addObject:v];
    }
    ArBot = [array copy];
    [array release];*/
}
...
```

Comment: First, How is defined a variable pointing to the view containing the buttons? (Yes, I´m new in Objective-C programming)... and Second, The view contain others buttons that no have to include in this Array, then, I can put the 25 button in a Box container and then apply the first or then second option... isn´t it?

Comment: How can I define a variable pointing to a Nview or NsBox for get 25 buttons in an Array?

Comment: When you create a variable for an object, you actually store a pointer to the object, so any object variable is a pointer to the object. You could put the buttons you want into a box, or use tags to fiter the buttons you want. To get a variable for the view or box, just use an IBOutlet and connect it in Interface Builder.

Comment: Ok, I just do it, but I get an error like a : 'view' undeclared here(not in a function). Why?

Comment: view is just a placeholder variable I used. You should replace it with the name of the IBOutlet you used.

Comment: Yes, I Understand you... I used 'Botons' in the connection, I write you 'view' for example continuation.

Comment: Error "'Botons' undeclared here(not in a function)"

Comment: NSArray *ArBot = [[BoxBot subviews] copy];
error: 'BoxBot' undeclared here (not in a function)

Comment: With the second option...
17> NSMutableArray *Arbot = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:25];
18> for(NSView *v in [BoxBot subviews]) {
19>    if([v isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]) [ArBot addObject:v];
20>}
I get two errors :
Botones.m:17: error: initializer element is not constant
Botones.m:18: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'for'
The numbers 17> 18> 19> are line numbers that I write for you convenience.

Comment: Can you edit the question with all of the relevent code? That would include header files and and the method where you load the array.

Comment: The code to load the array needs to be in your class somewhere. The best place would be the awakeFromNib method. Also, ArBot should be an instance variable, possibly also others. I will edit my post to show you.

Comment: Ok. Now, how can I access to, for example, change a title of a button of the Array? 
[Arbot(5) setTitle:@"OK"]; dont works.... how then?

Comment: [[ArBot objectAtIndex:5] setTitle:@"OK"];

Comment: Ok my friend. Thank you for your lesson about Objective-C Xcode program. I use to develope in Visual Basic and this is my first contact with this kind of language and platform. It's very different. I try to make other programs I made in VB on Xcode. Now I have another strange behavior in the program. In the 'if' sentences in the last, .. if (Fila > 0) {... no arrive, I put a breakpoint to control this and never arrive... This is strange because I thing that after the first if... else , should continue with the other if clause but not works... You Know?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that error to my post last time. The problem is (NSColor*)redColor or (NSColor*)greenColor. redColor and greenColor are not NSColor objects, but values used in an older drawing system. Instead, use [NSColor redColor] and [NSColor greenColor]

Comment: Ok Thanks... Have you read my last post? What you think about?

Comment: Yes, I think making those changes should fix it. You are probably causing an exception when you try to use the old constants.

Comment: Well, I made this changes and still not working, both, the button don't change of color and the program don't arrive in the second if...

Comment: Code updated, and I've remarked the line where don't arrive the program sequence..

Comment: Are you using custom buttons? The NSButton class doesn't support background colors, so calling setBackgroundColor: would cause an exception.

Comment: Yes I'm using NSButton..., Then... Is impossible to change backColor or Color of a button?

Comment: Right. You would have to create your own button class in order to do this. What you can do is show a small image on the button and change it.

Comment: To do this, I have to do simply to rename the NSButton?... And... I try the Arrays Button, but I think don't works, they don't change the title..

Comment: What do you mean rename the NSButton?

Comment: Sorry for my English... On Interface builder, when a select a NSButton, Push Enter and rename it with a name different. Isn't it?

Comment: That would be changing the title. Your code should change the title as is, as long as there are no extra views in BoxBot. If you want to use images, use setImage: and pass an NSImage object.

Comment: I tried to change the tittle because I couldn't change the BackgroundColor, but my intention is to change the BackgroundColor, And the Boxbot is a Outlet of a Box that contain, I think, because I put in it the buttons, all 25 buttons.

Comment: Add NSLog(@"%@",[Arbot objectAtIndex:5]); before that line and post what it prints to the log.

Comment: 2010-12-21 21:22:45.396 Apagallums[5909:a0f] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (5) beyond bounds (1)

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. Are you sure BoxBot is the box with the buttons in it? That error means there is only one object in the array.

Comment: Yes, there is only one Box, this have a outlet named BoxBot and the 25 Buttons are inside it, almost this is that I see in the window.

Comment: Change the log I gave you to NSLog(@"%@",[BoxBot subviews]); and post the new output.

Comment: 2010-12-21 22:43:38.704 Apagallums[6304:a0f] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (1)... I think I'm not getting data that where you wanted.. I get the data from Debugger Console...

Comment: That is where you should be getting the logs. Put NSLog(@"%@",[BoxBot subviews]); on the line before [[Arbot objectAtIndex:5] setTitle:@"OK"]; and post the new log.

Comment: 2010-12-24 14:19:18.121 Apagallums[749:a0f] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (5) beyond bounds (1)

Comment: There should be something else before that.

Comment: 2010-12-26 12:32:54.272 Apagallums[944:a0f] (
    "<NSView: 0x100402ec0>"
)

2010-12-26 12:32:54.274 Apagallums[944:a0f] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (5) beyond bounds (1)

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. This means that there is a view between the box and the buttons. Get rid of it if you can, but if it is too much work, just change [BoxBot subviews] to [[[BoxBot subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews]

Comment: Ok, now, How can I create a own button class to change it the backgroundcolor? How you said in ...Right. You would have to create your own button class in order to do this. What you can do is show a small image on the button and change it. – ughoavgfhw Dec 20 at 23:37

Comment: It is a lot more work to create a custom button. You should start a new question asking for advice.

Comment: This is a very, very much of work, sure, no ones explain me this.... well... I should continue searching.... Thanks.